# How to filter the values from xml file and print it to text file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, filter

```
<MasterCode>
    <Uid>119</Uid>
    <Name>Juan Gabriel MONTE</Name>
    <Category>LastName</Category>
  </MasterCode>
<MasterCode>
    <Uid>120</Uid>
    <Name>Atilla SELEK</Name>
    <Category>FirstName</Category>
  </MasterCode>
 <MasterCode>
    <Uid>121</Uid>
    <Name>barbosa filisa</Name>
    <Category>LastName</Category>
  </MasterCode>
```

This is an example of my xml file. i want to filter only the names that comes under the category last name. how to filter it and print the names in text file with C#?. Please help Thank u in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: _[LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview)_ is your friend

Comment: @TheTanic  _["Not all questions benefit from including code..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760/585968)_

Comment: @MickyD I know, that its not allways needed to provide code. But at least the OP should provide some informations what he tried, or what specific problem occured, while solving the problem. In addition: I did not ask for code, i just wanted to know what he tried

Comment: @TheTanic _"at least the OP should provide...what he tried...what...problem"_ - well no.  _["then there are problems that don't benefit from code at all...any code he might include is just a **waste of space**... **How do I frob a widget?**"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760/585968)_ which sounds awfully like _"How to filter the values from xml file"_

Comment: @MickyD I think we can agree, that we disagree on this point. In my opinion, this kind of questions are just the request for someone to write code for them. The comment secion is not the correct place to discuss that out, so I will stop from now on. If you want to discuss this, we can meet in a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232507/discussion-between-mickyd-and-thetanic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `XDocument` and `Linq`

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile2.xml");

var result = xmlDoc.Descendants("MasterCode")
    .Where(element => (string)element.Element("Category") == "LastName")
    .Select(x => x.Element("Name").Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Good though (my emphasis) _["You only have to create XDocument objects if you require the specific functionality provided by the XDocument class. In many circumstances, you can work directly with `XElement`. Working directly with `XElement` is a **simpler programming model**"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xdocument-class-overview)_. +1 regardless

Comment: Thank you for helping. And u asked for what i tried before i tried nothing went well so i just want some help .